# Error installing psycopg2 on python 2.6

Tags: python, psycopg2, easy-install

I'm trying to install psycopg2 on Python 2.6:

```
easy_install-2.6 psycopg2
```

but receive lots of compiling errors in psycopg/psycopgmodule.c
But psycopg2 is installed and works fine on the same machine on Python 2.4.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some of these errors? Did you try something else? pip for example?

Comment: psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:714: error: Б─≤c_api_objectБ─≥ undeclared (first use in this function)
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:717: error: Б─≤moduleБ─≥ undeclared (first use in this function)
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:717: error: Б─≤dictБ─≥ undeclared (first use in this function)
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:717: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:727: error: expected expression before Б─≤)Б─≥ token

Comment: Please include the whole output (and make sure it includes the *first* warnings and errors you get from the compiler) in your post. You are probably missing some headerfiles or library, but it's impossible to say without seeing the actual errors.

Comment: yes the hole output would be desirable. Can you check the first errors? Did you see something like this: Warning: /bin/sh: pg_config: command not found? What version of postgres do you use? If you use PostgreSQL Plus, try to do this: PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgresPlus/x.x/bin/ sudo easy_install psycopg2, where x.x is the version of PostgreSQL Plus. You have to try this because PostgreSQL Plus doesn’t put its header files or libraries in a standard place..

Comment: Thank you all! There were 2 problems: path to pg_config and missing python26-devel package.

Comment: I love "and stuff like that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add path to `pg_config` to `$PATH`
2. Install python26-devel